# Order Unique Clustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table that has around 20M rows and has about 500K rows inserted on a daily basis. There is currently no PK/Clustered index defined. I wanted to verfy my thinking was correct or not. The PK will consist of 2 columns, Dateloaded and Acctnumber. Acctnumber is unique for each day and Dateloaded is duplicated for every row. I am thinking it makes most sense from a read standpoint to have the index order Acctnumber, Dateloaded but from a load standpoint the exact opposite, Dateloaded, Acctnumber.

The data is typically used with a join on Acctnumber and either a join on Dateloaded or using Dateloaded in the where clause. Since, lately data load seems to be the more important, would Dateloaded, Acctnumber be the best?

Additional information there is currently an index on Acctnumber and one on Loaddate, Acctnumber (nonclustered) and the one for Acctnumber get used 100x more.

Comment: What are the **datatypes** of those two columns??

Comment: Always miss something. Sadly they are both Varchar(20) in this case. Already tried to convince them to switch dateloaded to DATE but they said no dice.

Comment: And there's no more suitable single column (like an `ID`) that could act as the primary clustered key ? A clustering key should be **narrow**, unique, stable and ever-increasing - `INT IDENTITY` is perfect. `VARCHAR` is bad for two reasons - too big (2 x 22 bytes) and variable length ...... this is **NOT** going to give you a very nicely performing clustering key

Comment: Agree on all fronts. I asked for a unique key, but they say no because those two columns make a unique key. They wont let me change data types because to much code is written using the current. Dateloaded will be increasing on a daily basis, so would Acctnumber, at least for new accounts.

Comment: Horrible logic on their parts...... you can *try* to create a clustered index with these two columns - but it'll be **far from ideal** .....

Comment: Yeah, i am just trying to determine which order is best.

Comment: Do you have any queries that use only one of the two columns in their `WHERE` clause? I'd use that column first, before the other.

Comment: Yes, as I said, just about anything will join on Acct but every will either join or use Load in the where. Acct would almost never be used in the where clause